# On click event generate html and check for duplicates

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies, plugins

What I am trying to do is to check for a click event and then generate html. The problem is that it generates duplicate values for me when the link is clicked more than once. Can anyone see what am I doing wrong? My code sofar:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.hotelComparison = function () {

    $('a.js-hotel-box').click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var obj =  $(this),                  
            hotelId = obj.data("hotel-id");
            ids = $.cookie("hotel-comparison");

         if(!ids){                          
            $.cookie("hotel-comparison", hotelId , { path: '/' });            
        }
        else{   
            $.cookie("hotel-comparison", ids + "," + hotelId , { path: '/' });      
        }
    });

    favouriteHotels();
};


function favouriteHotels(){

    var hotelIds = [];    
    $('.js-hotel-box').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var obj = $(this); 

        hotelIds.push({
            hotelId: $(this).data('hotel-id') ,
            hotelName: $(this).data('hotel-name'),   
            hotelImage: $(this).data('hotel-image')
        });

        // check for duplicate values 
        var dupes = {};
        var singles = [];            
        $.each(hotelIds, function(i, el) {
            if (!dupes[el.hotelId]) {
                dupes[el.hotelId] = true;
                singles.push(el);
            }
        });

        var html = '<ul class="favoriteItems">';

        jQuery.each(singles, function(index, value) {
                    html += '<li class="hotel-image">';     
                        html += '<a class="js-delete-hotel delete" id="'+ value.hotelId +'" href="#" title="Odebrat hotel  ze schránky"><span></span></a>';
                        html += '<img class="hotel_image" src="'+ value.hotelImage +'" width="70px" height="70px" />';
                        html += '<li class="hotel-name">' + value.hotelName + '</li>';
                    html += '</li>';
        });

        html += '</ul>';

        $('.hotelItems').append(html);

    });


}
```

}(jQuery));

Answer (score 0):

it's quite simple clicking twice gonna run function twice.

add a Boolean variable , and set it to true on function run.

and add condition, function will run only and only if variable is set to false.

and, initialize it as false.

And as i can see you are going through all your list in once and sandwiching it in `<ul>` . so what i am understanding with this is you are done with all your code.

so why are you using append. I mean append is meant to concatenate further and further.